# Gale-Shapley Implementation a multi-dimensional array issue

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, double, listiterator

I am implementing the Gale-Shapley algorithm to match passengers and taxicabs. So far, I've got a single preference structure (distance) to reject or keep the current match.

All seems fine and I think I am close to the solution. However, something odd is happening when accessing the preference data (multidim array). The second index, `kTaxiIndex`, has the right value but when indexing I am getting data from a different column in the same row! I have already moved variables around. Does anyone have the slightest clue what is happening here?

Any help is most welcome.

```
class TaxiScheduler {

    ArrayList acceptorTaxis;
    ArrayList proposorPassengers;
    Integer [] waitingList; //index represent taxis, contents passengers
    ArrayList<Integer> rejectionPool;   //where unmatched passengers are kept
    Integer [] rejectionCounter;    //determines the KBest option for that passenger
    Double [][] distancePreferences;      //unique preference structure

    public TaxiScheduler(){

    }

    public Integer[] doGaleShapley(ArrayList taxis, ArrayList passengers){

        acceptorTaxis = taxis;
        proposorPassengers = passengers;
        waitingList = new Integer [acceptorTaxis.size()];   //keeps best current match
        rejectionPool = new ArrayList<Integer>();   //rejected passengers' indexes
        rejectionCounter = new Integer [proposorPassengers.size()];  //keeps track of rejections per passenger
        distancePreferences = new Double[proposorPassengers.size()][acceptorTaxis.size()];

        initPoolandCounter();   //No passenger has been rejected, but all are included in the rejecion (not matched) pool
        calculatePreferences(); // distances between taxis and passengers

        /*
         * Every rejected passenger turns to its next (1st, 2nd, 3rd,...) closest taxi
         * Every taxi with more than one proposal keeps the closest passenger in the waitingList and 
         * rejects other proposing passengers
         */
        ListIterator<Integer> itrRejected = this.rejectionPool.listIterator();
        while(!this.rejectionPool.isEmpty())
        {
            if(!itrRejected.hasNext())  //end of list
                itrRejected = this.rejectionPool.listIterator();

            int newPassengerIndex = (Integer) itrRejected.next().intValue();
            int kTaxiIndex = getKBestOption(this.rejectionCounter[newPassengerIndex], newPassengerIndex); //Get K-best based on number of rejections

            itrRejected.remove();   //remove current passenger from rejected list

            if(waitingList[kTaxiIndex]== null ){ //taxi is vacant!
                waitingList[kTaxiIndex] = newPassengerIndex;   //match w/ closest taxi
            }else{ //compare, keep the best and pool rejected, update rejection counter
                int currentPassengerIndex = waitingList[kTaxiIndex].intValue();

                Double d1 = distancePreferences[currentPassengerIndex][kTaxiIndex];
                Double d2 = distancePreferences[newPassengerIndex][kTaxiIndex];

                if(d1.compareTo(d2) > 0){    //new passenger is closer i.e. d1 > d2
                   addToPool(currentPassengerIndex, itrRejected);   //add current passenger to pool and update rejection counter
                    waitingList[kTaxiIndex] = new Integer(newPassengerIndex);   //set new passenger as new match

                }else{  //current passenger is preferred
                    addToPool(newPassengerIndex, itrRejected);
                }
            }
        }
        Logger.getLogger("data").log(Level.INFO, "rejectedList = "+printPool(), "");
        return waitingList;
    }

    private void initPoolandCounter() {
        rejectionCounter = new Integer[this.proposorPassengers.size()];

        for(int i = 0;i< rejectionCounter.length;i++)
        {
            rejectionCounter[i]=0;
            this.rejectionPool.add(i);
        }
    }

    //Works with indexes, look up on preference structure
    private Double getDistance(Integer passengerIndex, Integer taxiIndex) {
        return distancePreferences[passengerIndex.intValue()][taxiIndex.intValue()];
    }

    /**
     *Fills the preferences structure with distances between taxis and passengers
     * 
     */

    private void calculatePreferences() {
        double distance = -1;
        StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();

        try {
            for (int iPass = 0; iPass < this.proposorPassengers.size(); iPass++){
                PassengerMovement passMov = (PassengerMovement) this.proposorPassengers.get(iPass);
                GeoPointExt passGeo = new GeoPointExt(passMov.getLatitude(),passMov.getLongitude());  
                buff.append(iPass+":\t");
                for (int iTaxi = 0; iTaxi < this.acceptorTaxis.size(); iTaxi++){
                    TaxiMovement taxiMov = (TaxiMovement) this.acceptorTaxis.get(iTaxi);
                    GeoPointExt taxiGeo = new GeoPointExt(taxiMov.getLatitude(), taxiMov.getLongitude());

                    distance = Haversine.getDistance(taxiGeo, passGeo, DistanceUnit.Kilometers);
                    this.distancePreferences[iPass][iTaxi] = new Double(distance);
                    //TODO: Inverted distances!!!
                    buff.append(distancePreferences[iPass][iTaxi].toString().substring(0, 5) +"\t");

                    //Logger.getLogger(TaxiScheduler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "PREFS = ["+passMov.getPassengerMovementPK().getMobileNo()+"]["+taxiMov.getTaxiMovementPK().getPlateNo()+"]");
                    //Logger.getLogger(TaxiScheduler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "PREFS = ["+iPass+"]["+iTaxi+"]("+this.distancePreferences[iPass][iTaxi].toString().substring(0, 4));
                  }
                buff.append("\n");
            }
        }catch(NullPointerException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(TaxiScheduler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "distance = "+distance, ex);
        }

        Logger.getLogger(TaxiScheduler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "TOTAL PREF = \n"+buff.toString());        

    }

    /*
     * Returns index of the taxi that is k-best option for that passenger
     * 
     * @param k The k-best (closest) taxi to be retrieved, 0 being the closest
     * @param passIndex The passenger index
     * @return  K-closest taxi index for this passenger
     */
    private int getKBestOption(int k, int passIndex){
        Double [] passPreferences = this.distancePreferences[passIndex];    //Preferences for the taxi in that index
        List<Double> pPreferences = Arrays.asList(passPreferences);
        ArrayList originalOrder = new ArrayList(pPreferences);

        Collections.sort(pPreferences); //sort taxi distances
        Double kDistance = (Double) pPreferences.get(k); //get k-smallest distance
        int ind = originalOrder.indexOf(kDistance);  //find index of this value in the original array, even if repeated still KBest
        return ind;
    }

    private String printPool() {
        StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
        int c = 0;

        for(Integer x:this.rejectionPool)
        {
            buff.append(x+"["+rejectionCounter[x]+"]  ");
            c++;
        }
        return buff.toString();
    }

    /*
     * Add this element to rejection pool and updates its rejection counter
     * 
     * @param passengerToPool Passenger index to add to the pool
     * @param itrRejected iterator used in the rejectionPool
     */
    private void addToPool(int passengerToPool, ListIterator<Integer> itrRejected) {
        //check whether this passenger is already in the pool
        int rIndex = rejectionPool.indexOf(passengerToPool);

        if(rIndex == -1){ //not in the pool
            this.rejectionCounter[passengerToPool]+=1;
            if(this.rejectionCounter[passengerToPool] < this.acceptorTaxis.size())  //if has not been rejected by all taxis
                itrRejected.add(passengerToPool);

        }else{  //was already pooled, leave it there and increase counter
            this.rejectionCounter[rIndex]+=1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might need to provide a bit more detail; the code is a little hard to follow, and it's not entirely clear what is supposed to happen, and what's happening differently from that.

Comment: @Dave Newton This is an implementation of this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gale-Shapley_algorithm algorithm. I didn't use this pseudocode though. It is implemented based on my own understanding of the problem and this case's peculiarities (i.e., only one preference structure is required). 

As mentioned, I did track the contents of each structure and all seems to work fine.

Comment: @DaveNewton
What is happening: When indexing the distancePreferences multidimensional array, I am getting the content of a different cell, even though the indexes are fine. Which is really weird, is that only the column index is wrong, that is retrieves a position in the same row (different column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to be the bearer of bad news but for a problem this specific with an algorithm of this complexity, you're unlikely to get a pinpoint answer.

What I can suggest to help you find your bug(s):

- You have a lot of collections, in particular arrays of differing sizes. It doesn't really surprise me that you're getting some "out of whack" positions given this
- It looks like you've taken an algorithm expressed in a non-OO language (or perhaps pseudocode) - it could be worth setting up a new class to represent a `Taxi` and a `Passenger`, holding all the pertinent details inside, rather than trying to index into a particular array position of a particular array
- You have a mixture of method parameters and member variables that means your `TaxiScheduler` can actually only deal with one call to `doGaleShapley()` at a time. This will probably bite you later on unless you move *all* those member variables into the method
- Using "naked" `ArrayList`s is a double-no-no: `List<Taxi>` gives you type-safety while not forcing your client to use an `ArrayList`
- Refactor your `doGaleShapley()` method into smaller, self-contained, well-named methods that **do one thing only**
- **Use Unit Tests** to simulate each possible situation. Each test should be named after a desired functionality (e.g. `shouldReturnEmptyWaitingListIfNoPassengersProvided`) and consist of `Given - When - Then` statements that set up a scenario, exercise your function, and verify the results are as expected. If you've refactored your big method into smaller ones, it will be very easy to name your tests and make sure you're covering everything. You can also use a code coverage tool like [Cobertura](http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/) to ensure all your branches are being hit.
- If, after doing all this, you still can't figure it out, you should at least have a smaller snippet of code that you can post here :-)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I do have the classes you mention  Taxi and Passenger, It just doesn't seem useful to move around instances which I don't actually need to use. As you can see I just need retrieve positions to compute the preference structure, for the rest indexes work fine. 

Will replace the ArrayLists to see what happens.

Comment: Could you suggest something punctual in regard to refactoring doGaleShapley? It seems pretty simple to me. This code unintentionally does look similar to the pseudocode here  en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gale-Shapley_algorithm.

Comment: I'd look at each `if` statement and pull those into well-named methods. You've already started doing that with your methods like `calculatePreferences()`. Aim for a method to be no more than 5-8 lines. You'll end up with a _lot_ of methods, but they will all read very well. And you may well spot your bug :-)